# Когда нужен lazy loading связаных сущностей в Hibertate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Есть несколько связанных сущностей. У сущности `Propose` в виде поля есть `User`. И связаны они таким образом:

```
<class name="ru.pravvich.model.Propose" table="propose">

    <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>

    <property name="sold" column="sold"/>
    <property name="description" column="description"/>
    <property name="mark" column="mark"/>
    <property name="model" column="model"/>

    <many-to-one name="auhtor"
                 column ="id_auhtor"
                 class="ru.pravvich.model.User">
    </many-to-one>
</class>
```

При выгрузке данных все время возникают проблемы с подгрузкой `User` так как транзакция еще не закончилась но и `User` еще не выгрузился из базы. К примеру вот такой кусочек DAO к которому происходит обращение из сервлетов:

```
private final AtomicReference<SessionFactory> factory;

public Propose getProposeId(final int id) {

    Propose result;

    try (final Session session = factory.get().openSession()) {

        session.beginTransaction();

        result = session.get(Propose.class, id);
    }

    return result;
}
```

И тут встает плохой выбор: Либо я ловлю `LazyInitializationException` и так и не получаю данные `User'a`, либо я должен оставить сессию открытой, что тоже плохо так как вообще не понятно кто и когда ее будет закрывать.

В связи с этим 2 связанных между собой вопросов:

**1.** Как понять нужна ли вообще включенная lazy загрузка? И не лучше ли добавлять в конфигурацию `lazy="false"` и закрыть проблему?

**2.** Раз такая возможность как lazy загрузки есть, да еще и включена по умолчанию, значит это важная деталь, и создатели библиотеки рассчитывают что ей будут активно пользоваться.

И вопрос в том: когда и как закрывать сессию? Неужели просто бросить ее открытой в расчете что в конце работы приложения у `SessionFactory` будет вызван `close()` и это все решит? Не будут ли эти открытые сессии накапливаться и создавать проблемы? Как это решается в типовых случаях?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В случае с many-to-one ленивая загрузка скорее не нужна. В JPA 2.0 это отношение по умолчанию жадное. А вот one-to-many наоборот ленивое. Представьте, что у вас есть код, который должен показать только ФИО какого-то `User` из базы. Но с этим `User` связано, предположим, 10 000 `Propose`. В случае жадной загрузки, вы основательно нагрузите СУБД выборкой данных, которые вам не нужны. Поэтому пользоваться ленивой загрузкой или нет и как именно пользоваться зависит от конкретной ситуации. Совет на все случаи жизни тут просто невозможен.

Comment: по поводу случаев где не нужна ленивая загрузка я понял. Но не понятно как и когда закрывать сессию если ленивая загрузка все же удобна как в Вашем примере с получением ФИО?

Comment: Как я и написал, универсальной рекомендации нет, зависит от конкретной ситуации. По-хорошему, надо открыть сессию, выгрести все необходимые для выполняемого в данный момент функционала данные и тут же закрыть её. Вы же уже в момент обращения к базе знаете, что именно вам понадобится.

Comment: а как выгрести данные? У меня в примере есть Propose и надо выгрести User до выхода из try. А как это сделать? Ну не System.out'ом же проходить по всем вложенным сущностям которые мне понадобятся. Как сказать что мне в данном случае нужно чтобы Propose вернулся с инициализированным User'ом а на пример остальное не надо? Или может лучше другой вопрос создать про способы инициализации вложенных сущностей..?

Comment: Один из вариантов - это указывать в HQL-запросе `join fetch`. Другой - использовать [Hibernate.initialize()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#initialize-java.lang.Object-). Третий - написать сервисный слой, генерирующий DTO на основе сущностей. Четвёртый - так писать алгоритм, чтобы обращение к данным было чётко локализовано. Вариантов много, а выбор зависит от контекста.

Comment: ок спасибо попробовал работает. Не понял только "сервисный слой, генерирующий DTO на основе сущностей" не могли бы чуть-чуть пояснить что имеете в виду?